# $lookup not working whle using on _id field in mongodb(mongoose)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am currently learning how to use the lookup queries for joins but not getting the expected output

Schema 1

```
State
{
 state_name: { type: String, required: true },
 country_name: { type: String, required: true }
}
```

Schema 2

```
User
{
  name: { type: String },
  state: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'State', required: true },
  createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
}
```

Query I tried

```
db.User.aggregate([
    { $match: { _id: ObjectId(b1b1b1) } },
    {
    $lookup: {
      localField: 'state',
      from: 'state',
      foreignField: '_id',
      as: 'user_info'
    }
  }, 
  ]).then(console.log)
```

Getting user_info as an empty array while I do have both documents like this

```
State
{
  _id: a1a1a1,//ObjectId
  state_name: "UP",
  country_name: "India"
}
```

```
User
{
   _id:b1b1b1,//ObjectId
   name: Test,
  state: a1a1a1,//ObjectId
  createdAt:"random date"
}
```

Output:

```
[{
_id:b1b1b1,//ObjectId
   name: Test,
  state: a1a1a1,
  createdAt:"random date",
userInfo:[]
}]
```

Comment: Can you try: `from: 'states'` ?

Comment: Woah! It worked. Thank you very much, but how does it work?

Comment: mongoose pluralizes your schema name when evaluates collection name